# Python3: list all installed packages and versions in a virtual environment programmatically

Tags: python-3.x, pipenv

I'm using pipenv to create a virtual environment and I'm writing write a script that fetches all the installed packages and puts in a dictionary their names and versions, just as pip list would do if called from within the virutualenv:

```
> C:\Users\my_project > pipenv shell
>(.venv) C:\Users\my_project > pip list
Package         Version
--------------- ---------
argcomplete     0.8.1
bottle          0.12.4
certifi         2020.6.20
colorama        0.4.3
cx-Oracle       7.3.0
cycler          0.10.0
...
```

Comment: ```os.system('pip list')``` does not work because it lists packages in the "global env" not the virtual env

Comment: @jabberwocky had already answered to a similar question. This solution works fine for me.


`import pkg_resources`
`installed_packages = {d.project_name: d.version for d in pkg_resources.working_set}`

Answer (score 3):

Something like following can be used

```
import subprocess
out = subprocess.Popen(['pip', 'list'],
           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
           stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
stdout,stderr = out.communicate()

print(stdout)
```

You can then parse the stdout in your desired format